# Looking for Desiccants

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am an engineer and not the best at chemistry, I am horrible at it, but I was wondering if it is safe to mix sodium hydroxide and calcium oxide to make a desiccant that also captures carbon monoxide?

I am asking because I am trying to make a high quality zero air generator and need to lower the humidity and carbon monoxide and this seemed like a way to do it.

Comment: Why would you want to mix NaOH with CaO? Yes, it is safe, but also useless.

Comment: Sodium hydroxide and calcium oxide would remove water and carbon dioxide, but they would *not* remove carbon monoxide. For any significant flow,  you would also have to figure out how to prevent the airflow from either clogging the "filter" or creating "channels" through the filter.

Comment: Can't you just buy sodalime to remove the CO2 and water? Won't do anything for the CO though.

Comment: I suspect there might be a typo and OP meant *carbon dioxide* $\ce{CO2}$, not carbon monoxide $\ce{CO}$, since both NaOH and CaO are suited for $\ce{CO2}$ adsorption. Also, you are right that this mix can help to get rid of trace amounts of water, however hydration is quite exothermic (e.g. your adsorber is going to get warm).

Comment: You will also need activated carbon to remove VOCs

Comment: I have other drying components and use both activated charcoal and Purafil. I am just looking to remove the small amount of moisture that remains, I am currently getting a dewpoint of -34 C but I need to get to -40C or lower. I also need to remove CO and CO2 and this just seemed like a way to go. I am still looking for a second CO scrubber but that was not this request, I must of typed monoxide by mistake; sorry. I have a CO scrubber that converts CO into CO2 I am just going to slow the air flow through to increase affect but I wanted a second CO scrubber. That's my next question for here.